# How apply only when table exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How make "apply" if table doesn't exist? I have error message 'Invalid object name 'dbo.Passport'".

```
select top 10 op.ID, *
from dbo.Car
outer apply (select case when OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.Passport', N'U') IS NOT NULL then
                (select top 1 ID from dbo.Passport)
            else null
        end as ID) as op
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to solve this. But why do you sometimes have a table, but sometimes not?

Comment: T-SQL statements are compiled *in full*. You can't have a single statement do *x* if an object exists and *y* if it doesn't; the statement would (as you have found out here) simply fail to compile due to it referencing an object that doesn't exist when the object doesn't and thus the statement cannot be run. When it does exists, the statement would obviously run without issue.

Comment: Side note, a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is not going to give reliable results. Also, why do you want to return the value of `op.ID` twice (as the first and last columns of the result set).

Comment: @ThomA
But I can execute [
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.Passport', N'U') IS NOT NULL
 select top 1 ID from dbo.Passport
]

Comment: Just don't do this and you'll be fine. why would table be gone

Comment: Those are **two** statements, @nozd. A logical flow operation followed by a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

As @jarhl mentioned, you need to use dynamic SQL to solve it. Since you didn't provide any input or expected output, I am assuming this :

```
CREATE TABLE Passport (ID INT);
CREATE TABLE Car (ID INT);
```

```
INSERT INTO Passport (ID ) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(152),(658);
INSERT INTO Car (ID ) VALUES  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(500),(156);
```

```
14 rows affected
```

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Passport', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC('
        SELECT TOP 10 op.ID, *
        FROM dbo.Car
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 ID
            FROM dbo.Passport
        ) AS op
    ')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 10 op.ID, *
    FROM dbo.Car
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT NULL AS ID
    ) AS op
END
```

| ID | ID | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 500 | 1 |
| 1 | 156 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XAYqFN14)